# will Flutter become faster after deployment?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, mobile

I run my Flutter app in emulator and physical device, but all of them ended up laggy UIs as compared to the other apps in my phone, is Flutter app gonna be less laggy I deploy it to Play Store or App Store as they will be built into the phone?

Comment: Are you running the app in debug mode?

Comment: YES, but now I Got how to solve it by using release mode, Thank you for asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we run the app on Emulator it is in debug mode. In debug-mode apps are slower compared to the release mode as debug mode enables additional checks such as assert etc. While release-mode apps are much faster, the animation is smooth and there is no lag, unlike debug-mode. I suggest you try the release-mode app on your phone, you can build a release build by using the following command.

> flutter run --release